# more details icon with or without labels?

Tags: usability, gui-design, icons, hud

i am working on the product details (PDP) page for ecommerce website , in the Information Section on the PDP (to the right of the main product image)for some information i need to add more details icon beside a specific information and the question is:

is it better for the user to add the (more details icon only) or the (more details icon with a details word or label near the icon) and when the user hove over one of them tooltip will appear ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

According to - [Icon Usability](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/icon-usability/) by Nielsen Norman Group

> To help overcome the ambiguity that almost all icons face, **a text
>   label must be present alongside an icon** to clarify its meaning in
>   that particular context. (And even if you’re using a standard icon,
>   it’s often safer to include a label, especially if you slightly
>   altered the icon to match your aesthetic preferences or constraints.)
>
> Icon labels should be visible at all times, without any interaction
>   from the user.

So definitely - **Icons Need a Text Label**

Comment: Do you have any example for that from UI perspective

Comment: @ahmedmansi http://www.chromecrashes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Task-Manager-More-Details-Icon.png

Comment: It's not the common "i" in a circle icon in the example above but the title to the right of it makes sure that every one will understand exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0):

**Using icons without labels is hard to justify for an e-commerce site.**

Just icons and no labels are an option when users can't read. An app for little children for example, or for international users when translation of the labels is not possible. Another argument that justifies icon-only buttons is when users are trained to understand the icons. For example a complex business application with lots of controls and little space for labels.

The arguments above don't apply for e-commerce sites. To keep the shopping process clear and smooth, use icons with labels. If space is an issue than it's the total design that causes usability flaws.